# How to fix 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql, docker

I'm developing a .Net api using Docker containers, but at the moment to ask a GET request in swagger, it throws back `" The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."` which has to do with a database connection failure.

This is the swagger's error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63LTd.png)

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file with Postgresql image setup:

```
`services:
 db:
   image: postgres
   restart: always
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
     POSTGRES_DB: my_db
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
   volumes:
     - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
 app:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   ports:
     - 5000:80
   depends_on:
     - db
volumes:
 postgres-data:`
```

This is the ConnectionString in `appSetting.json`:

```
`{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "Host=db;Port=5432;Database=my_db;Username=postgres;Password=example"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
`
```

And finally this the dbContext injection in `Program.cs`:

```
`builder.Services.AddDbContext<EnrollAppTesting>(o => {
     o.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    }
);`
```

I was expecting to make the basic Api operation(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) into database, but it clearly seems that database is not well configured nor settled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging this outside of the Docker container? I noticed your file name is "appSetting.json" whereas the default name is usually "appsettings.json" but perhaps this was a typo in your post and not in your file name. Keep in mind that the Linux filesystem is case sensitive. That may also play a part here.

Comment: No, I wrote it bad here. Its AppSettings in the folder project. How can I debbug it outside container? I dont know how to do this. I'm new on this.